# rails-upgrade - upgrade a rails2 app to rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade

I've an existing project in rails2 and I need to upgrade it to rails3.

I heard something about rails-upgrade but not used yet.

When I tried using `rails-upgrade check` it generate error like:

```
$ rails-upgrade check
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-upgrade-0.0.2/lib/rails-upgrade/upgraders/routes.rb:28: undefined method `cattr_accessor' for RailsUpgrade::Upgraders::RouteRedrawer:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-upgrade-0.0.2/lib/rails-upgrade.rb:12
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-upgrade-0.0.2/bin/rails-upgrade:7
    from /usr/bin/rails-upgrade:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/rails-upgrade:19
```

Any one please tell me how I can upgrade my app to rails3.

Comment: `cattr_accessor` is defined in `ActiveSupport` v 3+ Do you have rails v 3+ installed or this gem?

Comment: @Bohdan Pohorilets: 
`$ gem list | grep activesupport`
  
`activesupport (3.0.9, 3.0.7, 3.0.5, 3.0.4, 3.0.3, 2.3.8, 2.2.2)`
still the same problem

Comment: try to remove old gems and also there is a similar thread  http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/59288 and there is an advise to run `export RUBYOPT=-rubygems`

Answer (score 0):

I do the rails upgrades with creating a new rails project into the old one.

During the create procedure you should check the difference between those files that should be overwritten.

For me it was the fastest way to update my rails projects.